# Slowly fade out my main view Xml and go to another XML

Tags: android

Hai all
I want to slowly fade out my main view Xml and go to another XML?

Please anyone give me an example with a sample code.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own animation for window transformations via:

```
setWindowAnimations(resourceId);
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setWindowAnimations%28int%29) in the official android documentation.
Now you need to create an Animation that fades the first activity out and then slowly fades the other activity in. Have a look at the [animation package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) especially the [AlphaAnimation class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider fading in and out images instead of XML views then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471479/682778).