# Android fade in and fade out with ImageView

Tags: android, animation, imageview, fadein, fadeout

I'm having some troubles with a slideshow I'm building.

I've created 2 animations in xml for fade in and fade out:

**fadein.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
          android:duration="2000"/>
     </set>
```

**fadeout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
          android:duration="2000"/>
     </set>
```

What Im'trying to do, is to change images from an ImageView using the fade effect, so the currently displayed image will fade out, and another one will fade in.
Considering that I have an image already set, I can fadeout this Image without problem, with this:

```
    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.your_fade_in_anim);
    imageView.startAnimation(fadeoutAnim);
```

But then, I set the next image to be displayed:

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(secondImage);
```

It just shows up in the imageView, and when i set the animation it hides the image, the fade it in... Is there any way to fix that, I mean, when I do *imageView.setImageBitmap(secondImage);* command, the image do not shows up immediately, and only when the fade in animation is executed?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To implement this the way you have started, you'll need to add an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) so that you can detect the beginning and ending of an animation. When onAnimationEnd() for the fade out is called, you can set the visibility of your ImageView object to View.INVISIBLE, switch the images and start your fade in animation - you'll need another AnimationListener here too. When you receive onAnimationEnd() for your fade in animation, set the ImageView to be View.VISIBLE and that should give you the effect you're looking for.

I've implemented a similar effect before, but I used a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) with 2 ImageViews rather than a single ImageView. You can set the "in" and "out" animations for the ViewSwitcher with your fade in and fade out so it can manage the AnimationListener implementation. Then all you need to do is alternate between the 2 ImageViews.

**Edit:**
To be a bit more useful, here is a quick example of how to use the ViewSwitcher. I have included the full source at https://github.com/aldryd/imageswitcher.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/sunset" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/clouds" />
    </ViewSwitcher>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    // Let the ViewSwitcher do the animation listening for you
    ((ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) v;

            if (switcher.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
                switcher.showNext();
            } else {
                switcher.showPrevious();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks man! I forgot about the serVisible!
And thanks for the ViewSwitcher tip, it's seems easier than handle everything by myself.

Comment: @Aldryd Is this more efficient performance-wise? As compared to the selected answer(separate XML file)?

Comment: @Ron I didn't really compare the performance of the different methods. Compared to decoding/working with bitmaps for the ImageView objects, I would think that using a ViewSwitcher versus implementing the AnimationListener yourself would not be very noticeable. I did recently find out that if you're using API 11 or above, you can use some new Animation classes. You can see an example of crossfading 2 views with API 11 here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

Answer (score 101):

I wanted to achieve the same goal as you, so I wrote the following method which does exactly that if you pass it an ImageView and a list of references to image drawables.

```
ImageView demoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DemoImage);
int imagesToShow[] = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3 };

animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0,false);  



  private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final int images[], final int imageIndex, final boolean forever) {

  //imageView <-- The View which displays the images
  //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
  //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[] 
  //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

    int fadeInDuration = 500; // Configure time values here
    int timeBetween = 3000;
    int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    //Visible or invisible by default - this will apply when the animation ends
    imageView.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
    fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    imageView.setAnimation(animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex) {
                animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1,forever); //Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array
            }
            else {
                if (forever){
                animate(imageView, images, 0,forever);  //Calls itself to start the animation all over again in a loop if forever = true
                }
            }
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For showing how the fade in and out animations can be defined in code, you sir, get my vote

Comment: You could also count repeats and do a Array.lenght%count in your onAnimationRepeat method

Comment: @Crocodile Do you think there could be memory issue in your code. Let the activity with the above code keep on running. It will create so many AnimationSet Objects. Is there any possibility that it will crash with outOfMemory after some time ?

Comment: @Gem - why would that particular allocation cause an issue?  Every time imageView.setAnimation(animation) is called any reference to a previous animation is lost, so the garbage collector would be able to delete this previous object.  AFAIK, not a memory issue.

Comment: How can i set this for overlapping?

Comment: @Crocodile This worked as expected but it stops after the first loop. To go on indefinitely, change `animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0, false);` to `animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0, true);`

Comment: Please change `if (forever == true)` to  `if (forever)` and reformat code.

Answer (score 48):

Have you thought of using TransitionDrawable instead of custom animations?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html

One way to achieve what you are looking for is:

```
// create the transition layers
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), firstBitmap);
layers[1] = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), secondBitmap);

TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
imageView.setImageDrawable(transitionDrawable);
transitionDrawable.startTransition(FADE_DURATION);
```

Comment: This is the best answer for this question.

Comment: Sorry for the bumping, but if I use this in an Handler, and have it in a permanent loop, the app loses performance in an other constant fade in/fade out animation I have. Any recomendations?

Comment: TransitionDrawable can only handle two images/layer.

Comment: Transition drawable causes AppNotIdleException when running espresso test

Answer (score 8):

I used used fadeIn animation to replace new image for old one

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.ALPHA, 0.2f, 1.0f).setDuration(1000).start();
```

Comment: See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html for cleaner code.

Comment: THANK YOU!! still relevant... What I needed the most right now!

Comment: Thank you!! This is the best answer...very simple to implement and works smoothly.

Comment: the cleanest, thank you! in my case i think fits better: (... 0.6f, 1f).setDuration(450)...

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by two simple point and change in your code

1.In your xml in anim folder of your project, Set the fade in and fade out duration time not equal

2.In you java class before the start of fade out animation, set second imageView visibility Gone then after fade out animation started set  second imageView visibility which you want to fade in visible

fadeout.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

fadein.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="6000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

In you java class

```
Animation animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    animFadeOut.reset();
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(animFadeOut);

    Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    animFadeIn.reset();
    iv2.clearAnimation();
    iv2.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
```

Answer (score 3):

For infinite Fade In and Out

```
AlphaAnimation fadeIn=new AlphaAnimation(0,1);

AlphaAnimation fadeOut=new AlphaAnimation(1,0);


final AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);

set.addAnimation(fadeIn);
set.addAnimation(fadeOut);
fadeOut.setStartOffset(2000);
set.setDuration(2000);
imageView.startAnimation(set);

set.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        imageView.startAnimation(set);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this kind of routine for programmatically chaining animations.

```
    final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out); 
    final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in); 

    anim_out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            ////////////////////////////////////////
            // HERE YOU CHANGE YOUR IMAGE CONTENT //
            ////////////////////////////////////////
            //ui_image.setImage...

            anim_in.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
            });

            ui_image.startAnimation(anim_in);
        }
    });

    ui_image.startAnimation(anim_out);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and the easiest way, for me was this..

->Simply create a thread with Handler containing sleep().

```
private ImageView myImageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shape_count); myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shape1);
    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.w("hendler", "recived");
                    Animation myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.fadeout);
                    myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation);
                    myImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000); // your fadein duration
            }catch (Exception e){
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best solution you'll get. Simple and Easy. I learned it on udemy.
Suppose you have two images having image id's id1 and id2 respectively and currently the image view is set as id1 and you want to change it to the other image everytime someone clicks in. So this is the basic code in `MainActivity.java` File

```
int clickNum=0;
public void click(View view){
clickNum++;
ImageView a=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.id1);
ImageView b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.id2);
if(clickNum%2==1){
  a.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000); //alpha controls the transpiracy
}
else if(clickNum%2==0){
  b.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000); //alpha controls the transpiracy
}

}
```

I hope this will surely help