# Android Viewgroup: fade/blend two views on top of each other

Tags: android, animation, view, transition

I want to fade from one view to another on in a `ViewGroup`.
At the moment I'm doing the transition using `setAlpha`, but the problem is that only one view is being rendered, the one that was on top and is fading out.

- Is the view-array inside `ViewGroup` an order by z-axis?
- Is only the top view being rendered?

My `layout` method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b) {
    L.debug("laying out {} children", this.getChildCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
        L.debug("layout out {}", i);

        View view = this.getChildAt(0);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What a stupid mistake. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use ViewSwitcher? It does exactly what you want. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720626/android-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-imageview).

> Is the view-array inside ViewGroup an order by z-axis?

There is no such thing like Z-order in android. Views are drawn in oder they were added to ViewGroup. First added draws first.

> Is only the top view being rendered

No, android will draw all views in visible rect even if they are totally overlaped by others.

I think you should fix this place this.getChildAt(0) and layout all childrens in your ViewGroup.