# android imageview with multiple image fade in fade out animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

its my first time to ask question here...
im hoping that somebody could help me....

i want to animate multiple images that animates as `fade in` and `fade out`. i was able to animate one imageview but what i need is once the first imageview fade out, the second imageview must fade in and so on...

it should loop once the application is opened. thanks

here is how i call the animation in my java **onCreate()**,

```
   final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bsc);
   final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,     R.anim.fadein);
   image.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
   final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
```

**fade in.xml**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
      <alpha 
         android:fromAlpha="0.1" 
         android:toAlpha="1.0" 
         android:duration="2000" 
         />
    </set>
```

**fade out.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha 
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
    android:toAlpha="0.1" 
    android:duration="2000" 
    />
 </set>
```

Comment: You may find my previous answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10471479/682778

Answer (score 2):

Try using AnimationListener.

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bsc);
final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);

AnimationListener animListener = new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hsc);
            image.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
        }
    };
image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(animListener);
```

If you want to loop, then put another listener on animationFadeIn also. This will again start animationFadeOut. Pick images from an array and display.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity.xml layout create a new ImageView, please note I'm not using the attribute  `android:src="@drawable/...."`  in this ImageView , like this

```
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/uno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       />
```

So you will have two imageViews in your Activity.xml finally

1.-Your first image (the original in your code)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bsc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/your_first_image/>
```

2.-the new image without `android:src` attribute

```
 <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/uno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       />
```

In your activity class  `onCreate()` define the new image you want to use, of course you need to save this image in your drawable folder, and then set the image with its drawable using `setImageResource()` method, the code will be something like this;

```
ImageView nueva = null;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         //....your code...
         nueva = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uno);
         //Here set the new image 
         nueva.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_new_image);
}
```

Now just need to add the animations, in `onResume()` method for example:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
          //the imagen you are using in your code
           image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
           //the new image fadein
           nueva.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);


    }
```

Comment: never EVER name your variables or anything in your code on your local language, everything must be in English