# Android animation's continuous loop is not happening

Tags: arrays, loops, android-animation, fadein, fadeout

i just copied the code below from this link  [Android fade in and fade out with ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720626/android-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-imageview) 
but i don't understand why the continuous loop is not happening. Im thinking maybe the (forever) variable doesn't have an initial value for the condition to be tested. Will somebody help me figure out what should i do to make this code work perfectly?...

(The reason i copy and paste this code to ask a question is that i dont have the privilege to make comment on the original posts, sorry for this.)

I hope somebody could help me.... thanks

```
ImageView demoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DemoImage);
 int imagesToShow[] = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3 };

animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0,false);  



 private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final int images[],
 final int        imageIndex, final boolean forever) {

 //imageView <-- The View which displays the images
 //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
  //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[] 
 //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the 
   first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

int fadeInDuration = 500; // Configure time values here
int timeBetween = 3000;
int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    //Visible or invisible by default - this will apply when the animation ends
imageView.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);

Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
animation.setRepeatCount(1);
imageView.setAnimation(animation);

animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex) {
            animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1,forever); //Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array
        }
        else {
            if (forever == true){
            animate(imageView, images, 0,forever);  //Calls itself to start the animation all over again in a loop if forever = true
            }
        }
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In this code return infinite loop work when the value of `forever` is `true`. but at the beginning of the code there is `false` in the function.

**TRY**

replace

```
animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0,false);// at line 3
```

By

```
animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0,true);
```