# Android fade out with ImageView when clicked

Tags: android, animation, imageview, onclicklistener

I want to create an ImageView in a service class. I want to fade out my image when user clicked on it. I try below code:

```
        ImageView chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_20);
        final Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(50);
        fadeOut.setDuration(3000);

        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                chatHead.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        });

        chatHead.setAnimation(fadeOut);

        chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

  }
        });
```

When I click on image of ImageView, it disappears immediately!

Answer (score 0):

```
 chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

you need to start your animation after above line

```
fadeOut.start();
```

like

```
  chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                fadeOut.start();

      }
  });
```

Comment: why do you want to hide the image when the button is clicked ?  `chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` Why not `chatHead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: sry i don't understand your question!

Comment: when are you are clicking the image you are setting it invisible mode and then starting the animation.  `chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`  remove that part and you can see the fadeOut

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are calling `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` in your image `OnClickListener`.

Redefine your `OnClickListener` method like so:

```
chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fadeOutAndHideImage(chatHead);
            }
        });
```

Define `fadeOutAndHideImage` method:

```
private void fadeOutAndHideImage(final ImageView img)
  {
    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                  img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    });

    img.startAnimation(fadeOut);
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782260/making-a-smooth-fade-out-for-imageview-in-android) for reference.

Comment: image not disapear never :(

Comment: don't have any idea??