# Slideshow Animation Loop Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-resources

So I have implemenented a fragment of code which works perfectly found on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471479/2976351)

The code is listed below :

```
    private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final int images[], final int imageIndex, final boolean forever){

    //imageView <-- The View which displays the images
    //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
    //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[] 
    //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

    int fadeInDuration = 500; // Configure time values here
    int timeBetween = 3000;
    int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Visible of invisible by default
    imageView.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //Add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
    fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    imageView.setAnimation(animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if(images.length -1 > imageIndex){
                animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1, forever); // Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array.
            }
            else{
                if(forever == true){
                    animate(imageView, images, 0, forever); //Calls itself to start the animation all over again in a loop if forever = true
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Basically this code accepts an Array of images and creates a slideshow with fadeIn and FadeOut effects. Once it reaches the end the animation stops. How can I modify the code to keep animating forever?

Comment: tried a for loop till the end of seq?

Comment: There is the forever boolean in the signature of the method, tried to use it?

Comment: So you are saying that I have to replace the if statement with a for statement?

Comment: Am using it on the else statement but it doesnt seem to work properly!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution Guys.

Just had to make a slight alteration! On the else statement I had to set Forever to false!

```
            else{
            if(forever == false){
                animate(imageView, images, 0, forever);
            }
        }
```