# How to fade out activity when we finish it?

Tags: android, android-activity, fadeout

I have an `Activity` with a button. If user clicks `Button`, I start a service and finish this `Activity`. I want to fade out it. How to do it? I tried some ways but they seems not to work.

Comment: please post what you tried so far and also post your code.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?
Some animation?

Answer (score 5):

the smallest and best way i found is to put code:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

into OnClickListener, or where ever you want to finish activity with fade.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem with ObjectAnimator.

```
ObjectAnimator objAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mainView, View.ALPHA, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            obj.setDuration(2000).addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }
            });
            objAnimator.start();
```

Comment: This is practically one of the most convenient methods.. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Fade out and Fadein using Android(java)

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1); // fadein
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);//Fadeout
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);
```

I trust this is helpful to you for more refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720626/android-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-imageview)