# Changing ImageViews with For Loop in AnimationListener - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio

I want to make an animation where a set of ImageViews fade in/out one after another after the user presses a button. I made an array of the images (r1, r2, and r3) called list but it says the index "i" has to be declared final. Is there a way to traverse the array so each ImageView is animated?

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
   r1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.r1);
   r2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.r2);
   r3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.r3);
   final ImageView[] list = {r1, r2, r3};

      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            animation1.setDuration(1000);
            animation1.setStartOffset(2000);

              for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {    
                animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {                     
                        list[i].startAnimation(animation2);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });

                animation2 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
                animation2.setDuration(1000);
                animation2.setStartOffset(2000);

                animation2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                        list[i].startAnimation(animation1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });

                list[i].startAnimation(animation1);

        }
    });
}}
```

}

Comment: then declare `int i` outside `onCreate` method

Comment: Possible answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10471479/4617458

Comment: @GaganSethi Thanks for the link. When I try to make the animation start  with a button.setOnClickListener, why does it give an error of "Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."