# changing images with fade animation

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I need to create animation where I will display 3 images. Each image should completely fade in and fade out (slow blink) and then next image should be shown. I have done it by creating 3 animations. Each animation starts the next animation in onAnimationEnd listener:

```
private void startAnimation() {
   final Animation aniIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.fade_in_out);
   final Animation aniIn1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.fade_in_out);
   final Animation aniIn2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.fade_in_out);

   aniIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            ivRandom0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ivRandom0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivRandom1.startAnimation(aniIn1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    aniIn1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            ivRandom1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ivRandom1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivRandom2.startAnimation(aniIn2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    aniIn2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            ivRandom2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           showFinal();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

   ivRandom0.startAnimation(aniIn);
}
```

For that animation I have this xml which sets alhpa from 0 to 1 and back to 0:

fade_in_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true">

<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    />
</set>
```

here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/images_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image_random_0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img_generator0"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image_random_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img_generator1"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image_random_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img_generator2"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Although this is working, I don't like the nested callbacks. It is also causing memory leak as it is holding reference to imageviews in calbacks.

Is there a better way how to create this kind of animation? Or at least avoid the memory leak? I was trying imageswitcher, but it is causing cross fading of images which I don't want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use ObjectAnimator , it has methods to setDuration and start delays , which you can calculate according to your need.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha",0, 1);
objectAnimator.setDuration(DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION);
objectAnimator.setStartDelay(milliseconds);
objectAnimator.start();
```

you can create three different object animators to set accordinglt . for more [refer this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)

Comment: Hi Muhib, Thank you for your answer. I have created the animation with the delays as you suggested. It seems that everything is working as it should and no chaining of animations through listeners is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewswitcher to implement this behaviour. Please see the code below:

**layout**

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/sunset" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/clouds" />
</ViewSwitcher>
```

**code**

```
((ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) v;

        if (switcher.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
            switcher.showNext();
        } else {
            switcher.showPrevious();
        }
    }
});
```

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720626/android-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-imageview)

Comment: Thank your for your answer but this is not working. `ViewSwitcher` can contain only 2 child views. And as I wrote in the question, I was trying also`ImageSwitcher`, but ti was causing crossfading which I don't want.