# Null pointer exception when fade in animating in android studio

Tags: android, animation, nullpointerexception

I am making a fade-in animation to a textview in my project
but the application crushes with a null pointer exception

the target is the last textview with id(long_click)
and here is the xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_more_options_passowrd_groups"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="arb.passwordmanager.more_options_passowrd_groups"
    android:background="@drawable/settings"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#88FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/groups_layout">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="@string/char_group"
            android:textColor="#222222"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/char_group_explain"
            android:textColor="#444444"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkboxes"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            ></LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#FF4444"></View>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/check_uncheck_all"
                android:id="@+id/checkall"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/long_click_item"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:id="@+id/long_click"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the animation xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="3000" >
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0" android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

the function which calls the animation is

```
void text_fade_in()
    {
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_click);
        Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
        textView.startAnimation(animation);//the exception is here
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_more_options_passowrd_groups);
        text_fade_in();
    }
```

the animation file is located in R.anim.fade_in

the error is the following

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{arb.passwordmanager/arb.passwordmanager.more_options_passowrd_groups}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at arb.passwordmanager.more_options_passowrd_groups.text_fade_in(more_options_passowrd_groups.java:170)
                      at arb.passwordmanager.more_options_passowrd_groups.onCreate(more_options_passowrd_groups.java:176)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30468 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8618', transport: 'socket'
```

I tried to change the target of the animation to another view in the same activity and yet getting the same result

after solving the problem the animation is not working as like there is no animation at all
i updated the animation file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:fillBefore="true" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0" android:toAlpha="1" android:duration="3000" />

</set>
```

but still the animation is not working
help me please

Comment: post the complete code and error details

Comment: replace `yourXMLcontainsTextView` with your layout file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to call `setContentView(R.layout.yourXMLcontainsTextView);` before `text_fade_in();` function call

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourXMLcontainsTextView); // add this , otherwise there is no design
    // linked with your activity and cannot be found using findViewById
    text_fade_in();
}
```

Comment: it partially works
the application does not crush anymore but the animation is not running 
the target textview is remaining the same as if there is no animation

Comment: @AhmadRajab try adding the duration into `alpha` instead of `set`

Comment: still not working
help please

Comment: @AhmadRajab if still doesn't work the add interpolator to define the appearance of your animation , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720626/android-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-imageview

Comment: is it related to fillbefore or fillafter properties of the animation xml
i tried to make them true but still the same

Comment: still not working

Comment: post the updated code at the end of your question

Comment: you solved my main problem thank you very much
I think the animation problem happens because the animation with onCreat 
I should make an independent thread for it

Comment: your activity and it's views are completely visible after on resume, so try overriding onresume and call `text_fade_in` from it otherwise last option is adding button and cllicklistener

Comment: I can not avoid onResume because it is essential for other features of the activity
I solved the probele using onWindowFocusChange() listener and it works
Thanks for your help