# fade out first, and then fade in, is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to run animation set: **fade out first, and then fade in**, but is **not working**, this is code:

```
TextView iv_1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
AnimationSet animSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils
                       .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout_first);    // fadeout_first.xml
iv_1.setAnimation(animSet);
```

**fadeout_first.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--fade out first-->
    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="1"
           android:toAlpha="0"
    />

    <!--and then fade in-->
    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="0"
           android:toAlpha="1"
           android:startOffset="2000"/>
</set>
```

but when I change the order(**fade in first, and then fade out**), it is **working well**:

```
TextView iv_1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
AnimationSet animSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils
                       .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein_first);  // fadein_first.xml
iv_1.setAnimation(animSet);
```

**fadein_first.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--fade in first-->
    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="0"
           android:toAlpha="1"
    />
    <!--and then fade out-->
    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="1"
           android:toAlpha="0"
           android:startOffset="2000"/>
</set>
```

why?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720626/android-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-imageview

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false">

    <!--fade out first-->
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <!--and then fade in-->
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />


</set>
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
 TextView iv_1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
 AnimationSet animSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout_first);
 iv_1.setAnimation(animSet);
```

Comment: Can you add little bit description over your answer?, It would be helpful.

Comment: thanks! but it not answer that I expected. I need `startoffset`, not the same time.

Comment: @Guo it also working with `startoffset` i have test it

Comment: I run your code in my device: the first few second it's black screen, the last show textview,  and no any animation.

Comment: @Guo can u share any sample gif or video of your requirement

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to add `gif` in comment